# Permutations with condition

Tags: python, permutation

community!

I'm trying to solve this task:

Input: I have a list of words.
Output: I need to return list of permutations each follows that conditions:

- all permutations have a neighbour in input list
- the order of list elements can not be changed

Example:

```
In: ['cat', 'sat', 'on']
Out: [('cat', 'sat', 'on'), ('cat', 'sat'), ('sat', 'on'), ('cat'), ('sat'), ('on')]
```

Explaining example: permutation ('cat','on') is not allowed cause 'cat' and 'on' aren't neighbours in Input list. Permutation ('cat','on','sat') isn't allowed cause 'on' in inout list is more right when 'sat', but in this permutation the order of words weren't saved.

I've tried to write this function and clear result of it after:

```
def findsubsets(S,m): 
    return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))
```

But i think, that then we generate all possible combinations (in the majority os situations i have lists with a lot of words), we are using a lot of memory, so i'm trying to find solution, that won't generate combinations and after i will choose permutations that i need. I'm finding for clear solution, without additional transformations.

I am writing on `Python 3` and i am looking for a solution of these task with least memory. I was searching similar questions on this site, but haven't found.

Thank you in advance for solving this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to write this function and clear result of it after:

`def findsubsets(S,m): 
return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))`


But i think, that then we generate all possible combinations, we are using a lot of memory, so i'm trying to find solution, that won't generate combinations and after i will choose permutations that i need. I'm finding for clear solution, without additional transformations.

Comment: You should update your question with that

Comment: Add info in question

Comment: itertools.combinations is lazy, meaning it only generates if necessary (when doing one iteration). And the `set(...)` is essentially the same as `{x for x in itertools.combinations(S, m)}`, which makes the set-approach not actually use more ram, only more cpu-time for the internal loop. The combinations which are not needed do only exist for one loop cycle. But oldwookis solution avoids these additional cycles by using a clever second loop perfectly fitting your needs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A short recursive approach:

```
original = ['cat', 'sat', 'on']
def combos(d):
  yield tuple(d)
  yield from ([] if not d else combos(d[1:]))
  yield from ([] if not d else combos(d[:-1]))

result = list(set(filter(None, combos(original))))
```

Output:

```
[('sat', 'on'), ('sat',), ('cat',), ('on',), ('cat', 'sat'), ('cat', 'sat', 'on')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is
a set of possible sublist, which you can get with by simple loops.

```py
original = ['cat', 'sat', 'on']
result = []

n = len(original)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
        # Append tuple(original[i:j]) if that's what you are looking for
        result.append(original[i:j])

print(result)
```

```py
[['cat'], ['cat', 'sat'], ['cat', 'sat', 'on'], ['sat'], ['sat', 'on'], ['on']]
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel this is the most helpful answer, please accept this by clicking the check mark.